# TortoiseGit context options missing for files

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have the latest TortoiseGIT 64 bit installed on my Windows 7 64 bit machine.
I noticed recently that context options are no longer coming on the files. The folders have the options such as Git commit, Rename etc...but right clicking the files, shows the menu which normally comes for un-added files such as 'Add..' only. I have checked in my repository, that these files for sure are version controlled.

I have already installed 64 bit tortoisegit, latest version of git, have rebooted multiple times, have tried uninstalling tortoisegit, and reinstalling. Have also tried repairing tortoisegit setup.

Anything else I may try?

Here are how my menus are looking:

[image]

Comment: Did you try a fresh clone of your repo? Sounds like something might be broken in it.

Comment: Well no, but the same problem is visible in all my other repositories on the system. Anyway just cloned in a new directory and got same issue there too :(

Comment: Tried killing TGitCache.exe with TaskManager?

Comment: @MrTux, not yet. But after your comment, killed that process from taskmanager. What does it do? Post killing, I reopened that folder, but still no file level commit/rename menu options.

Comment: I've also got the same problem, had it for a long while. I know there is a bug for it

Answer (score 14):

Well, I seem to have found a solution for now.

Changing the Icon Overlays status from Default to 'Shell Extended' seem to have brought back the menus and icons for me!

Changing it to None had not helped.

[image]